# Android conversion to Kotlin. How to call inner method in constructor super

Tags: android, class, kotlin, constructor, super

This is the method I have:

```
private static class AvatarNotFound
        extends Throwable
{
    public AvatarNotFound(String message, @NonNull AddressableAvatarView addressableAvatarView)
    {
        super(message + getErrorMessageSuffix(addressableAvatarView));
    }

    private static String getErrorMessageSuffix(@NonNull AddressableAvatarView addressableAvatarView)
    {
        return ". Addressable: " + addressableAvatarView.toString();
    }
}
```

converting to Kotlin it returns this code, which will become this:

```
   private open class AvatarNotFound(message: String, addressableAvatarView: AddressableAvatarView) : Throwable(message + getErrorMessageSuffix(addressableAvatarView)) {

    private fun getErrorMessageSuffix(addressableAvatarView: AddressableAvatarView): String {
        return ". Addressable: $addressableAvatarView"
    }
   }
```

But it says that `getErrorMessageSuffix` is an unresolved reference?
How can I make the constructor recognise it?

Comment: You could put `getErrorMessageSuffix` inside [the `companion object {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html)

Comment: Yesm thanks!!! This was it. It works now. If you make an answer with this, I will accept it as the correct one. 
And sorry, still new to kotlin, so sometimes it gets confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this may help you:**

```
companion object{
        private fun getErrorMessageSuffix(addressableAvatarView: AddressableAvatarView): String {
            return ". Addressable: " + addressableAvatarView.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use companion object here, which will enable to access your method with class name.

```
companion object
    {
        private fun getErrorMessageSuffix(addressableAvatarView: AddressableAvatarView): String 
         {
            return ". Addressable: $addressableAvatarView"
        }
    }
```